# How to loop a command in Terminal (MAC OS X) without homebrew etc

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I have a question.

Is it possible to loop a command in terminal without homebrew or Xterm (MAC OS X)?

F.e. I want to run a python script and it stops/ends every two hours.
I'm really lazy and don't want to re-run that script manually.

Would be nice to get some help.

Have a nice day!

-Jason

Comment: Sounds like you want a basic cron job. Although this doc seems to indicate launchd is preferred. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html

Comment: Or maybe a service, especially since it sounds like you want to command to restart after it ends, not run on an exact schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to set up a cron job to run every two hours. Type crontab -e then:

```
0 */2 * * *  python [full path to command]
```

Comment: I'll just add, to edit your crontab use `crontab -e` which will launch vim by default.

Comment: @CollinD On my system, it uses the env variables `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` if set, then defaults to `/usr/bin/editor`, which happens to be Nano – so not necessarily vim.

Comment: That makes sense, I was moreso indicating what will happen on a 100% fresh osx environment.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to run a command repeatedly would be to run it in a shell `while` loop, e.g.

```
while true; do python my_script.py ; done
```

This will work in a shell script, as well as on the command line.

Comment: Thanks guys for all great responses! That's my solution :)